# How to get total pixel size of the screen

Tags: vb.net

I am writing an application that generates graphs.  I need to set the bar size according to the size of screen (in pixels) 
How can I get the total screen size in pixels using vb.net code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Screen.PriamryScreen.Bounds.Height
```

or:

```
My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width
My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height
```

Alternatively you can look at `Screen.WorkingArea` which gives you the dimensions of the working area (that excludes docked windows, toolbars etc.)

Answer (score 3):

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
```

Comment: +1, but it's reccomended that you always provide context with your code, and not...just code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Dim intX As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Dim intY As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
```